# References check time difference

Tags: references

A company asked for references

The job is in Canada while references are in Australia

if they are going to call the reference during working hours in Canada that means it will be mid-night in Australia.

I don't want them to call the references in the middle of the night or at non-convenient time..

Will it be ok if I suggested to contact references by email instead of phone to avoid time difference issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Will it be ok if I suggested to contact references by email instead of phone to avoid time difference issue?

Normally your new company should know that. You shouldn't act like you assume they don't. I'd say don't **suggest**, if at all then only mention it along the way. But I wouldn't do even that if not we were talking about it anyway.

You are giving a first impression on you to them. keep in mind they might ask if they really want to employ someone telling them what to do from the first moment. One more reason to not overreact.

Even if you don't mention this fact, you don't give them your boss' private number? If they call the company at midnight there should be no problem for anyone.

Comment: I would also suggest that most folks would probably opt for an email to a place like Australia over a phone call for the first contact. I'm not even sure I could place a phone call from my work phone to Australia.

Answer (score 1):

When writing down references, I would include the country in this case (when it's different from the one you're applying in). If they're smart, they'll understand there's a time difference themselves.

You can include email addresses to your references, when they cannot reach them at their business number, it might be helpful to schedule a call by email. Make sure they're up-to-date!